# I am a PhD student. How can I find collaborators that I can contribute work to and become a coauthor on papers?

Tags: publications, phd

I'm a PhD student almost completely on my own at my university.  I'm in my third year and its occurred to me I have had to drive every project forward almost entirely on my own.  I am the only student working on my topic in the world (I am working on a new remote sensing technique invented and patented by my supervisor).  However, because of this I have no one to get advice from and work with apart from my supervisor.  I am envious of others in my department (astrophysics) who get to collaborate together and gain far more support and papers.  I have had to push forward all of my papers (two first author) largely on my own.  I am keen to become a co-author on other work but I'm not sure how I join existing projects.  Does anyone have similar experience?  Could I just cold email scientists who might be working on projects I could contribute to?  I'm really struggling and alone

Comment: Why are you keen on becoming a co-author in the first place? What does that get you?

Comment: I suppose just increasing number of papers with my name on it.  My colleagues have a large number of papers to their name with comparatively less effort (i.e. they don't lead the study and do the majority of the work).

Comment: As a PhD student your job is to get your PhD. Now it will depend on where you are and their requirements, but multiple first-author papers is good. Sure, one or two papers with others to show either your flexibility or an application of your technique to other problems might be good. But get your degree above collecting papers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that cold emailing will be entirely unfruitful. The way to start collaborations is to meet people and discuss ideas with them. Professional meetings are a good, maybe the best, way to do this, but you can't just passively attend them.

Other things that might be possible for some people is to have the university invite outside speakers who spend a couple of days interacting with graduate students and faculty. Or, one might be able to arrange a short visit elsewhere, give a talk, and spend a day or two interacting.

You probably need to finish your degree first, but make it a goal to meet and interact with people and to have those topical conversations with them.

I'll note that in some fields it is completely natural to interact as a student with only your advisor. Other faculty members probably have different interests than yours (and your advisors).

Make travel/conference support one of the things you look for in employment. Make departments with faculty that have similar interests a priority in job search. In some university departments, the coffee lounge is the most important room for idea development and exchange.

Over time, one can develop a circle of collaborators, but it won't be overnight and it is unlikely to get started with cold emails.

If all else is closed, it might be possible to have your advisor send emails to people in their circle, introducing you and suggesting you have something to offer. An email from a colleague is likely to be answered and requests more likely to be honored than any cold email from a student.

Comment: Thank you for your message.  I am hoping to attend a couple of conferences this year and make visits to universities.  Is it normal for academic careers to sometimes take more time to get going?  I'm just worried that I'm falling behind my colleagues who collaborate together extremely frequently whereas I have been a bit more of a one man band.